# togglable tabs in rails 3.2 bootstrap

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I would be happy if i'll be able to work with a togglable tag in rails 3.2.
I used this code :

```
div class="tabbable">
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="proftabs">
  <li><a href="#profile_tab"  data-toggle="tab" >Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="#friends_tab" data-toggle="tab">Friends</a></li>
  <li><a  href="#photos_tab" data-toggle="tab">Photos</a></li>
  <li><a  href="#videos_tab" data-toggle="tab">Videos</a></li>
  <li><a  href="#quotes_tab" data-toggle="tab">Quotes</a></li>

   <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="profile_tab" class="tab-pane">
            aaa
        </div>
            <div id="friends_tab"  class="tab-pane">
            bbbbb
            </div>
            <div id="photos_tab"  class="tab-pane">
          cccc
            </div>
            <div id="videos_tab"  class="tab-pane">
            dddd
            </div>
            <div id="quotes_tab"  class="tab-pane">
           rrrr
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

but it doesn't work in rails. I mean, i'm not able to see the content of the tab. i red many solution on internet , even in stackoverflow, but i'm still in problem. can you help?

EDIT:

[image]

As you can see, if i click on a tab i would see something..but it doesn't happen. I really don't know what to do

Comment: Did not get what you meant by "i'm not able to see the content of the tab" ?

Comment: i edit the first post :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because of missing `ul` tag.

```
<div class="tabbable">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="proftabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#profile_tab"  data-toggle="tab" >Profil e</a></li>
    <li><a href="#friends_tab" data-toggle="tab">Friends</a></li>
    <li><a href="#photos_tab" data-toggle="tab">Photos</a></li>
    <li><a href="#videos_tab" data-toggle="tab">Videos</a></li>
    <li><a href="#quotes_tab" data-toggle="tab">Quotes</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="profile_tab" class="tab-pane active">
        aaa
    </div>
    <div id="friends_tab"  class="tab-pane">
       bbbbb
    </div>
    <div id="photos_tab"  class="tab-pane">
       cccc
    </div>
    <div id="videos_tab"  class="tab-pane">
       dddd
    </div>
    <div id="quotes_tab"  class="tab-pane">
       rrrr
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Updated answer for readers:

Ended up it's because Bootstrap.js was not included in `application.js`. Check out the comments for more information.

Comment: It's running fine here in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7fLjL558/). Is there any JavaScript error in your browser debugger?

Comment: I've added the `active` class on the first tab, in case if that's what you meant by "not able to see the content of the tab".

Comment: no, i didn't mean that. I have no error on JS. I don't know, but is it possible that i have to use jquery to change the active class on the clicked tab?

Comment: By default Bootstrap will handle the tab clicking, as long as you have jQuery and Boostrap.js inside your application. Did you include bootstrap inside your `application.js`?

Comment: oh my god..i didn't put //= require twitter/bootstrap into application.js . You save my life :D thank you!

Comment: Bootstrap.js include methods that handles the tab clicking to switch tabs using jQuery. Checkout http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs for more information.